# How can I move text to the left with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have some text that is inside a `span` element and I'd like to left-align it instead of the way it is now which is centered. I tried making a margin to the right and text center with CSS but that didn't work. Can you tell me how to do it? The text that I want to the left is  "(Jag arbetade: 4-6 timmar/vecka)" and now it is rendered centered if you look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/ugd83ucv/)

The code that I'd like to change is

```
<div id="i4c2" class="artBaseRow">
    <div id="i4_tbl_11" class="artWrapper">
        <table class="srtbl" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" summary="">
            <caption><b>Vad var det bästa med kursen?</b></caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="srtbl-h1">
                    <th class="srtbl-qt">
                        <div>
                            <br /> <span>(Jag arbetade: 4-6 timmar/vecka)</span>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So that the text "(Jag arbetade..." is aligned to the left alongside the heading. How can I do that?

Comment: Its already left aligned, whether you need to left align to body.

Comment: @stanze yes, I would like the text "(Jag arbetade.." to align with the next row. I tried adding styling to the span element but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css for `srtbl-qt` class (try put it at the end of CSS file)

```
.srtbl-qt {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Also I don't know why you need div and break and span elements around that text, but it can be removed (*hint*: `th {padding-top: 10px;}`)

Answer (score 2):

### Where it comes from...

You have put your text inside a table heading `<th>` element. It's standard browser behaviour to apply `font-weight: bold; text-align: center;` on `<th>` in the so-called ***user-agent style sheet***.

### ... and how to solve it.

You need to specify what you want to override this behaviour, for example like this:

```
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the thing is the `span` elements has `display: inline` so its width is exactly the same as the text and like some of its parent has `text-align: center`, that makes is positioned in the center, so by doing only `text-align: left` doesn't works so you have to change its to `display: block` and then `text-align: left`

to clarify:

```
span-element{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

you can do too:

```
span-element{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: left;` to this class

```
.reportPage .srtbl .srtbl-h1 th, .reportPage .srtbl .srtbl-h1 td{
    text-align: left;
}
```